# Automate removal of TFS project template customization

Tags: azure-devops, project-template, opshub

**Background**

We're currently looking to migrate our TFS projects over to VSO.

To do this we're making use of the OpsHub tool.

VSO doesn't support custom templates (not until Summer at least, which is too late for us), and OpsHub can't migrate projects where the project templates in source and destination don't match.

As such we need to revert our TFS projects to use vanilla templates.
Microsoft have confirmed this / supplied a list of partners who could (for a fee) aid in unpicking these customization.

Before hiring in a third party I wondered if there were any tooling which could allow us to do this in house for relatively little pain.

**Question**

Is anyone aware of any tools or scripts which may aid in reverting from a custom TFS template to a vanilla one?  e.g. performing tasks such as:

- Mapping new lookup values to vanilla equivalents
- Moving new field's data to name/value pairs appended to the end of description or comment fields.
- Stripping custom fields/values from the template once the project's data has been updated as above & thus those fields have become superfluous.

**Glossary & Acronym Definitions:**

- TFS: Team Foundation Server
- VSO: [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx) (Since renamed VSTS)
- OpsHub: [TFS to VSO Migration Tool](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/vsomigrationutility)
- VSTS: Visual Studio Team Services

Comment: NB: It seems OpsHub's OIM package may be the answer, providing this custom to vanilla template mapping, and also allowing delta sync (i.e. sync projects, then allow changes to continue being synced over time so you don't have to one big freeze and migrate task for large migrations).  Not entirely clear atm though.  http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/oim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing customization is a fairly easy process which is briefly outlined at https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/setup/migrate-team-projects-vs (step 1b).

OIM will allow more flexible mapping and ongoing delta sync to allow for warm cutover. It is a paid product and with the additional knobs, it requires additional

Comment: Correct, its really simple and can be as simple as overwriting the original template. There will be data loss that way, but it will get you there.

Comment: Given that VSO doesn't support customizations, giving up customizations is a fundamental choice a customer has to make if they decide to move to VSO.

Comment: As work item customizations are coming task soon it will not be for much longer. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/news/release-archive-vso. Hopefully OpsHub have a version that suports customizations ready to go.

Comment: The link in the answer does not work. is there an updated link on how to remove process customizations?